# the advertisement dialog appears when Using Vs Elastic control provided by video soft in vb6

Tags: vb6, dialog

I am using a Video Soft Vs Elastic control and now when ever my application runs this dialog appears promoting video soft and after that my application loads. how do i get rid of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i took a workaround, used the already present VSElastics copied it to create a new one and then did bring it to front to show it. As it was behing the main VSElastic.
And now its workin.